# Showing LUB of subspaces equals the sum of the subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $S(V)$ denote the set of all subspaces of the vector space $V$. The set $S(V)$ of all subspaces of a vector space $V$ is partially ordered by set inclusion. The {$0$} is is the smallest element in $S(V)$ and the entire space $V$ is the largest element. And lets define the sum of two vector spaces as:- $$S + T = \{u + v|u \in S, v \in T\}$$ where $S$ and $T$ are vector spaces.

My question is why is the least upper bound (lub) of $S$ and $T$ equal to the $S + T$. 
$$S+T = \operatorname{lub} \{ S,T \}.$$ Intuitively, I would guess the union of S and T to be the lub. i.e. $$  S \cup T = \operatorname{lub} \{ S,T \}. $$ Why is my intuition wrong? (What did I miss?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the least upper bound of $\{S,T\}$ is the smallest **subspace** of $V$ that contains both $S$ and $T$.

In contrast, $S \cup T$ is not even a subspace (except in the cases where $S\subseteq T$ or $T \subseteq S$).

Comment: On some books though, the least upper bound is not defined like that. Instead they define posets and then define LUB and GLB. And from that definition there is no such restriction that LUB of two subspaces must also be a vector space. (Advanced Linear Algebra Steven Roman)

Comment: @noahabe Your poset here is $S(V)$, and by definition an upper bound of $\{S,T\}$ is some element $U$ of $S(V)$ (i.e. a subspace of $V$) such that $S \subseteq U$ and $T \subseteq U$. So a least upper bound (if it exists) must also be a subspace of $V$.